# Iterating through an NSArray and storing items in groups of 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nsarray

I've definitely tried to do my due diligence on this one but keep coming up short. I have an array of objects that I have parsed and I want to iterate through these and store them. Assuming the array is 144 objects (just an example), I want to store it in groups of 12 to display in a tableview cell. Actually of those 12 objects in the array I'll likely only be displaying 3-4 in the cell, but all of those objects in the detail view.

To help explain what I mean (sorry if it hasn't made sense at this point) here's some of the code I've got that is getting the data.

```
NSMutableArray *objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for (TFHppleElement *element in objectsNode) {
    PHSingleEvent *singleEvent = [[PHSingleEvent alloc]init];
    [objectsArray addObject:singleEvent];

    singleEvent.title = [[element firstChild] content];
}
```

This pulls down the entire array of objects (an unknown number but definitely a multiple of 12). How would I go about storing 12 objects at a time into a single event?

I can log the info with

```
PHSingleEvent *firstObject = [objectsArray objectAtIndex:0] // this one is null
PHSingleEvent *eventStartTime = [objectsArray objectAtIndex:1];
PHSingleEvent *eventEndTime = [objectsArray objectAtIndex:2];
...
PHSingleEvent *lastObject = [objectsArray objectAtIndex:11];

NSLog(@"single object of event: %@", eventStartTime.startTime);
NSLog(@"single object of event: %@", eventEndTime.endTime);

etc...
```

But the array keeps going past 12. I want to iterate up through each 12 objects and store those values, preferably as strings to be displayed in a cell and detail view.

Any ideas?

Thanks much in advance and I will be here to answer any questions if I was unclear.

C.

Comment: If I am wrong please correct me. Suppose you have 144 objects in an array, so you want to break that array in small 12 arrays with size 12?

Comment: Array indexes for 12 objects will go from 0 to 11. So your lastObject should be [objectsArray objectAtIndex:11]

Comment: Also, if you are storing a specific kind of information at a specific index, using a NSDictionary would be better. That way you wont have to keep track of the indexes, just the keys can be used

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi - not quite. I want to be able to make each set of 12 properties so I can populate a single event cell with those items. The next cell would have the next 12 items, etc. An example would be something like.. objectAtIndex:1 would be "04/06/2014", objectAtIndex:2 = "04/07/2014" (start and end dates) and then a bunch of other data, finally getting to objectAtIndex:13 which would again be a start date. So objects 1, 13, 25, 37, etc would all be "start dates" and every time I get to a start date in the list, I want to make sure it is a separate event and loads in the next cell.

Comment: @akashg you're right... just a late night typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: I've just added an answer that uses both approaches: 2D array with dimensions n*12, and NSDictionary. Please let me know if either works. I would strongly recommend using NSDictionary, as it is easier for memory, storage and retrieval purposes. Also, as @akashg mentioned, it will save you the trouble of tracking indices of individual objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a for loop? Assuming that each event object has 12 sub-objects (i.e. indices 0 - 11) you could achieve storing it by using a mod function. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *eventArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<objectArray.count/12;i++){
    int offset = 12*i;
    NSMutableArray *event = [objectsArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(offset, 12)];
    [eventArray addObject:event];
}
```

So now eventArray has n arrays, each of 12 objects (where n = totalObjects/12)

EDIT: A better idea would be to use NSDictionary. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *eventArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<objectArray.count/12;i++){
        int offset = 12*i;
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [objectsArray objectAtIndex: offset], @"eventStartTime", [objectsArray objectAtIndex: offset+1], @"eventEndTime", ..., [objectsArray objectAtIndex: offset+11, @"lastObject",nil]; 
        [eventArray addObject:tempDict];
    }
```

Then you can access each of the above objects using a similar statement as shown below:

```
PHSingleEvent *eventStartTime = [[eventArray objectAtIndex: index] objectForKey: @"eventStartTime"];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! This is certainly looking like what I was trying to fumble through to break out the data. I'm working on it now and will let you know if it works.

Comment: Thanks again, this worked out perfectly for me. I am using an array of dictionaries now to populate the table and detail views. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This method will return an array of smaller arrays based on the group size you specify.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)makeGroupsOf:(int)groupSize fromArray:(NSArray*)array
{
    if (!array || array.count == 0 || groupSize == 0)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *bigGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.count; )
    {
        NSMutableArray *smallGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:groupSize];
        for (int j = 0; j < groupSize && i < array.count; j++)
        {
            [smallGroup addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
            i++;
        }
        [bigGroup addObject:smallGroup];
    }
    return bigGroup;
}
```

I haven't tested it or anything though. After you have the big array with the smaller array(s) it is just a matter of filling each cell with any desired number of objects from the sub arrays.

Note: You might want to handle the cases when the array is empty, null or the group size is 0 differently.